# Hiding Properties in Derived C# Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, inheritance

I have four classes which share some arrangement of four properties. I have currently set the base class to be `abstract` with each property marked as `virtual`. Then in each of the four derived classes I am overriding the properties which it uses and ignoring the others.

The problem is that I can still access all properties in each of the derived classes, regardless of whether I have overriden it from the `abstract virtual` property in my base class.

I have a feeling that I am approaching this from the wrong angle. Is there a way to explicitly hide or block properties, or is there a better approach.

Comment: If you don't want alle the properties to be available in the derived classes, then why define them in the base class at all?

Comment: Because all properties in the base class are used by at least one of the four derived classes, but not all.

What I'm thinking is having 4 interfaces for each of the properties. The derived classes can then choose to implement the interfaces which defines the properties it needs.

Comment: @JMs: As other people have also pointed out, it sounds like the design should be different, but I have too little information to go on to be able to suggest what it should be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you should rethink your inheritance hierarchy. Consider the following heuristics:

If two or more classes share only common data (no common behavior), then that common data should be placed in a class that will be contained by each sharing class.

If two or more classes have common data and behavior (i.e., methods), then those classes should each inherit from a common base class that captures those data and methods.

If two or more classes share only a common interface (i.e., messages, not methods), then they should inherit from a common base class only if they will be used polymorphically.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it's not possible to hide members in a derived class .(that's against the inheritance rules) To solve this problem you can have two level of abstract classes.In level one there's a base class with all the members that should be among all the derived classes , in second level you can have special classes with only the members you want to be inherited from this class down.

```
//Level1
public abstract class Employee
{
public string Name{get;set;}
public abstract double CalculateSalary();

}

//Level2
public abstract class CalssAEmployee:Employee
{
public int NumberOfWorkingHours{get;set;}

}

public abstract class ClassBEmployee:Employee
{
public int NumberOfSales{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove/hide methods or properties in derived classes as this contradicts liskov's substitution principle.

You can override the properties to throw Exceptions but this is no good Design.

You should have in a class only the members which are actually valid on this class.

Maybe you want to define several interfaces having your properties and let each class implement the interfaces you need.

Comment: Yeah, that is the approach I was thinking of as I wrote this question. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind reflection and casting you could try something like this using helper methods.  The example below assumes there is a base class for Orders which isn't shown here:

```
public abstract class Client : Entity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string  Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual string  Requirement { get; set; }
    public virtual string  Complaints { get; set; }
 }

public class GreatClient : Client
{
    public virtual List<GreatOrder>  Orders { get; set; }
}

public class WebClient : Client
{
    public virtual List<BadOrder> Orders { get; set; }
}

public static class ClientHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<Order> GetOrders(this Client client)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Client>>
                         {
                             {typeof (GreatClient), () => { return ((GreatClient) client).Orders;}},
                             {typeof (WebClient), ()=> { return ((WebClient) client).Orders;}}
                         };

        return result[dto.GetType()].Invoke();
    }
}

//Client code
Client client = new WebClient();
client.GetOrders();
```

A friend showed me this little pattern, thanks Nap.  Like I said it uses reflection and casting but can make object models very elegant when dealing with base classes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of rules in play here.

if you have an abstract class, with virtual properties, they can either be protected or public and this is what the outside world will see. When you extend/inherit this class, you can override these properties but not mark them as private. Private is the only way to hide a property from the derived class. Having a private property in abstract class will hide it from the children. But that is obviously not the case in your scenario.